# UnitTest embedded in the Oracle OSB code

Tags: unit-testing, junit, soapui, osb

I'm struggling to UnitTest OSB code as there is no real unit test framework to do that. Actually the only way to test an OSB service is to use SoapUI. The problem with OSB is that You can test the service using only the endpoint.

So my idea was to create in-line unit tests.
The code would contain conditional blocks and read the unit test key passed in the SoapUI request.

Something like:
UT1

In the code itself there would be a block called UnitTest1 Stage and inside a condition:

if(UT1) { 
    test it...
}

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrTDo.png

Keeping it like this makes it clean and its "separated" from the code logic.

Afterwards the SoapUI will read the response and check results using assertions. That Way I'm able to test all possible scenarios.

But the big question comes - should such code be run in production?

Because the choice is really limited here:

- embedded unit tests fully automated with hudson or
- no test at all (for the scenarios that are not testable using soap ui)

In my opinion is better to have it 100% tests so TDD could be used, automated regression would come in place, etc..

What do You think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we've got a solution. We've created a Xquery & xslt java testers using junit. 
For the OSB itself we've created a unit test framework that basically uses the WLST scripts that change the endpoints of the osb components switching to mocks for ws, calls, db adapters, jms, anything. We're doing this from the SoapUI using (groovy + python), so the testing of the OSB components is happening in isolation. Additionally we're capturing the input requests of the underlying osb business components (DB adapters, onther services) and store this in a JMS queue.

Afterwards using HermesJms we can retrieve the requests and perform assertions to check if the data was correct. And this is all happening in an automated way so we don't have to got to the OSB console anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Testing OSB nodes is difficult at the best of times.

Perhaps an easier route would be to convert the more complicated transforms to xquery (as is recommended), then [test it using JUnit](https://github.com/TrentBartlem/osbutils/tree/master/XQTestFramework).

The next step would be to hook up SoapUI as part of your build pipeline, so you can test the OSB flow. You can customise to point your biz refs at a SoapUI mock service as you deploy, so you can test independently of other services.